# How to disable the android back button in certain screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I would like to disable the android back button only in some pages. I used the following code:

```
  componentWillUnmount(){
      //For disabling the back button on cellphone
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }
    componentWillMount() {
         ParkToolbar.init( this );
    }

    //For disabling the back button on cellphone
    handleBackButton() {
        ToastAndroid.show('you cannot return', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
        return true;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        toolbarActiveItem = this.state.user; 
        ParkToolbar.setActiveItem(this.props.navigation.state.params.activeSection);

        //For disabling the back button on cellphone
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
    }
```

The problem is that, when I use the code in one page(Screen) in my program, the back button will disable in all pages(Screen) in every part of my application. Do you have any idea how to manage it in such a way that it only disable the back button for a single page(screen)?

**UPDATE:** 
I have also tested the code with BackAndroid and the same problem occurred.

Comment: Due to a typo you're not removing the back button handler. In ComponentWillUnmount change the `BackAndroid` to `BackHandler`

Comment: @AsafDavid: Thanks for your answer. I have also tested this one, but it gives me the same problem.

Comment: Anyway you should replace it to `BackHandler` as the one you're using is deprecated https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backandroid.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To disable Android Device Back Button , you can do like this , It will handle Back Press , Just add These Methods inside your Respective Activity :-

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButtonClick);
    }

    handleBackButtonClick = () => {
        this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
        return true;
    };
```

Comment: `componentWillMount` is deprecated up from React 16.3. Change it to `componentDidMount` instead.

Comment: I had to remove `this.props.navigation.goBack(null);` to get it to work. Not sure why this is the case. Probably that call bubbles up the navigation?

Answer (score 10):

When using the functional components this is worked for me (in this example i wanted to disable hardware back from DetailService)

```
 import {useRoute, useFocusEffect} from '@react-navigation/native';
 import { BackHandler } from 'react-native'
  

 function DetailService(props) {
  const route = useRoute();
      
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      const onBackPress = () => {
        if (route.name === 'DetailService') {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      };

      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
    }, [route]),
  );
......
```

Answer (score 4):

I used `useEffect` with navigation in react native.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButton);

    return () => null
}, [])


export const handleBackButton = () => {
    ToastAndroid.show('Back button is pressed', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
    return true;
}
```

If you don't return then it will disable back button across all screens. So make sure to unmount the component when screen changes from the current one.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the android hardware back button in certain screens we have to use the BackHandler from react-native itself and we have to use NavigationEvents reference of react-navigation.

```
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

_onBlurr = () => {
  BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',
  this._handleBackButtonClick);
}

_onFocus = () => {
  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', 
  this._handleBackButtonClick);
}

_handleBackButtonClick = () => true

render() {
  <View>
     <NavigationEvents
       onWillFocus={this._onFocus}
       onWillBlur={this._onBlurr}
     />
       {// Your View Here}
  </View>
}
```

References:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to put this inside your component:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => true);
  }, []);
```

Then back button press will be overriden without triggering action.

Comment: You are forgetting to remove the event listener on unmount